# Azure portal is not showing traces for a Java app running in a Docker container

Tags: java, azure, docker, trace, azure-application-insights

I have a Docker Windows container where a Jetty 7.4.0 server starts and deploys a Java 7 web application. The app contains an ApplicationInsights.xml file with the instrumentation key to monitor the app and trace logs in Azure portal.

After downgrading AI version to 1.0.9 (there are some problems with v1.0.10), Azure shows log traces perfectly when the app is running in my IDE or local server. According to this, the XML is succesfully found and well-configured.

The problem comes when the app is running into the container because I can see requests in Azure portal but the app traces aren't shown.

My ApplicationInsights.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">

  <InstrumentationKey>...</InstrumentationKey>

  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.initializer.docker.DockerContextInitializer"/>
  </TelemetryInitializers>

  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule"/>    
  </TelemetryModules>

</ApplicationInsights>
```

Does anybody know what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please post your ApplicationInsights.xml to show your configuration?

Comment: You could refer to the steps mentioned in the official tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-docker and the sample project on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Docker

Comment: @JayGong you can see now my ApplicationInsigths.xml on the post. I followed that tutorial but I cannot run the command _docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock -d microsoft/applicationinsights ikey=000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444_ because my container is a Windows based container and the path doesn't exist. Anyway, I think the tutorial explain how to monitor telemetry and what I really want is see the log traces like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-trace-logs